# How to use ConnectApi in a VF page having readOnly="true" attribute?

Tags: apex, visualforce, connect-api, chatter-feed, dmlexception

I've a VF page which have `readOnly='true'` attribute and I am trying to implement a button that when clicked will make a chatter post with some Blob content as element attachment using ConnectApi namespace classes in Apex.

I'm receiving this error:

```
Too many DML statements: 1
```

My code looks something like this:

```
<apex:page readOnly="true" controller="MyTestPageController">
This is a test page.<br />
Post Content of some Visualforce Page as content into a Chatter Feed.<br />
<br />
<apex:commandButton value=" Post Content to Chatter " action="{!postToChatter}" />
</apex:>
```

The Code Apex class looks like this:

```
public with sharing class MyTestPageController {
    public MyTestPageController() { }

    public void postToChatter() {
        PageReference p                                         = Page.MyTestVFPage;

        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput                  = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
        feedItemInput.subjectId                                 = 'me';

        ConnectApi.ContentCapabilityInput contentInput          = new ConnectApi.ContentCapabilityInput();
        contentInput.title                                      = 'My File';

        ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput capabilities    = new ConnectApi.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
        capabilities.content                                    = contentInput;

        feedItemInput.capabilities                              = capabilities;

        Blob myBlob                                             = p.getContent();
        ConnectApi.BinaryInput binInput                         = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(myBlob, 'application/x-excel', 'Data_File_'+Datetime.now().getTime());

        ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(null, feedItemInput, binInput);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest if I can make ConnectApi do chatter post without me having to remove readOnly="true" VF Page attribute?

Comment: what is the if you remove the **readOnly="true"**?

Comment: It works in that case. I've corrected the error msg received in my post above, when `readOnly=true` and this is something that I need in my app.

Comment: if readOnly="false" works for you then why you are not using?

Comment: because as I said, that would break an existing functionality. readOnly attribute allows for higher records fetch limit.

Comment: can you use @future methods to post the feedElement?

Comment: tried that as well - received following error `@future call currently not allowed`

Answer (score 0):

When you set readOnly attribute of page to true then it doesnot allow any DML statements.